# How to get Polkadot address from private key?

Tags: node.js, polkadot

I'm looking for a nodejs code to get the Polkadot address from their private key.

If is possible for chains polkadot and kusama.

I don't found any example searching o google and also on github.

Someone can help me?

Thanks!